# Can't do manual backup of ndb datastore from datastore admin

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Been trying for the last two hours and it keeps telling me that the job already exists:

From the logs:
Backup "datastore_backup_2017_06_30" already exists. (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/backup_handler.py:853) Traceback (most recent call last): File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/backup_handler.py", line 839, in _ProcessPostRequest raise BackupValidationError('Backup "%s" already exists.' % backup) BackupValidationError: Backup "datastore_backup_2017_06_30" already exists.

However, there is not a job running as far as I can tell. The last time I did one was this morning:

Started:    June 30, 2017, 9:27 a.m.
Completed:  June 30, 2017, 9:28 a.m.

Anyone hd similar or have a solution

Answer (score 2):

The logs are telling you exactly what the problem is.  The backup you did today at 9:27AM already has the name "datastore_backup_2017_06_30".  To do another, it must have a unique name.  Try adding a time to the backup filename, or change it to "datastore_backup_2017_06_30_2".